# Dual spaces and dual basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If V is a finite dimensional vector space over the field F  with dual space V* = Hom(V,F) . How to prove every ordered basis for V* is the dual basis for some basis for V ?

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  What are the elements of the dual space?  What makes a subset of $V^*$ a *dual basis* to some basis of $V$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ be the dimension of $V$, and let $\{b^1,\ldots,b^n\}$ be an ordered basis for $V^*$.  Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be some basis for $V$, and let $\{e^1,\ldots,e^n\}$ be the dual basis for $V^*$, so $e^i(e_j)=\delta^i_j$. Then there exist coefficients $\{a_{ij}\}_{1\le i,j\le n}$ in the field over which the vector space is taken, such that $b^i=a_{ij}e^j$ for all $1\le i\le n$ (summation convention in force). Then $b^i(e_k)=a_{ij}e^j(e_k)=a_{ij}\delta^j_k=a_{ik}$. Since, for all $1\le i\le n$, there exists at least one $1\le k\le n$ such that $a_{ik}\neq0$, and this gives you the required basis for which $\{b^1,\ldots,b^n\}$ is the dual basis.

Comment: If {b^1, . . . ,b^n } is the required dial basis then shouldn't it be equal to the kronecker's delta when applied .. here its giving aik's which could be particular constants .

Comment: I didn't finish it; my comment about one of the coefficients being non-zero was meant to imply that you can divide by it, thus getting a Kronecker delta

Comment: Means that some basis which makes the ordered basis , a dial basis is ek/aik

Answer (score 7):

Hint: given a basis $(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$ of $V^*$, it has a dual basis in $V^{**}$; use the canonical isomorphism $V\to V^{**}$.

---

For any vector space $V$, define the map $\omega_V\colon V\to V^{**}$ by $\omega_V(x)=\hat{x}$ such that, for $\xi\in V^*$,
$$
\hat{x}(\xi)=\xi(x)
$$
is a well-defined linear map (verify). If $V$ is finite dimensional and $x\ne0$, there exists $\xi\in V^*$ such that $\hat{x}(\xi)=\xi(x)\ne0$ (just complete $x$ to a basis). Therefore $\omega_V$ is injective.

The existence of a dual basis entails that $\dim V=\dim V^*$ and therefore also $\dim V^*=\dim V^{**}$. Hence $\omega_V$ is an isomorphism.

In particular, if $\{\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n\}$ is a basis of $V^*$, there exists its dual basis in $V^{**}$ and we can assume it is of the form $\{\hat{x}_1,\dots,\hat{x}_n\}$ for some $x_1,\dots,x_n\in V$, because $\omega_V$ is an isomorphism.

Since we have chosen a dual basis, we have, by definition,
$$
\hat{x}_i(\xi_j)=\delta_{ij}
$$
(Kronecker delta), which amounts to saying that
$$
\xi_j(x_i)=\delta_{ji}
$$
and so $\{\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n\}$ is the dual basis of $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$.

Comment: To prove V~V** ....???

Comment: @RipanJeet It's the main property of dual spaces.

Comment: which property ??

Comment: @RipanJeet That for a finite dimensional vector space $V$ the map $x\mapsto \hat{x}$ where, for $\xi\in V^*$, $\hat{x}(\xi)=\xi(x)$ is an isomorphism $V\to V^{**}$.

Comment: @RipanJeet I added the full proof (only requires easy verifications).

Comment: So nice of you thank you .. 

Comment: How to complete x to a basis ?

Comment: @RipanJeet This is basic theory of vector spaces: any linearly independent set can be extended to a basis.

Comment: Yes .. thank you ..

Comment: Very nice and detailed! +1

Comment: @egreg  In the last line where you wrote :$\hat x_i(\xi_j)=\delta_{ij}$", I have a question:  By definition $\hat x_i(\xi_j)=\xi_j(x_i).$ But, $\xi_j(x_i)$ *will only be equal to $\delta_{ij}$ if,* $\xi_j$ is the jth coordinate function of $V$ wrt the basis $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ which we are considering.

Comment: @ThomasFinley $\{\hat{x}_1,\dots,\hat{x}_n\}$ is the dual basis of $\{\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n\}$ by assumption. Thus $\xi_j(x_i)=\delta_{ji}$ because $\hat{x}_j(\xi_i)=0$.