# Find equations for $W$. and Find the $dim(W)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ the subspaces of $Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ formed by all matrix such that 
the sum of their rows is equal to zero.

$W=\{A\in Mat_n\mathbb({R}):a_{11}+...+a_{1n}=...=a_{n1}+...+a_{nn}=0\}$

> a)Find equations for $W$.
>   
> b)Find the $dim(W)$

For other question the buddy @Gribouillis help me to find a basis for $W^\perp$.

**His proof**

Let $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$ be the linear forms *sum of the $k$-th row*
$$\varphi_k(A) = a_{k,1}+\cdots+a_{k, n}$$
Obviously, $A\in W \Rightarrow \varphi_k(A) = 0$, hence $\varphi_k\in W^\bot$. Let $S = \text{Span}(\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n)\subset W^\bot$,
then $A\in S^\bot \Longleftrightarrow \forall k\in [1,n], \sum_j a_{k,j}=0
\Longleftrightarrow A\in W$. Hence $W^\bot = (S^\bot)^\bot = S$ and $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$ is a basis of $W^\bot$.

Edit: Let us recall the definition of $S^\bot = \{A \in Mat_n(\mathbb{R})\ | \ \forall \alpha \in S, \alpha(A) = 0\}$.

Edit2: Remark that the forms $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_k$ are independent because if for $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}$
$$\alpha := \lambda_1 \varphi_1+\cdots+\lambda_n\varphi_n = 0,$$
then one has $0 = \alpha(E_{k,k}) = \lambda_k$ where $E_{k,k}$ is the matrix which all terms are $0$ but the $k$-th term on the diagonal which value is $1$.

**My work:**

> b) We know $dim(W)+dim(W^\perp)=dim(Mat_n(\mathbb{R}))\Rightarrow dim(W)=dim(Mat_n(\mathbb{R}))-dim(W^\perp)=n^2-n$.
>
> **for the part a) i have a doubt.**
>
> We know $W=(W^\perp)^\perp\rightarrow W=\{A\in Mat_{n}(\mathbb{R})|f(A)=0\forall f\in W^{\perp}\}=\left\{A\in Mat_{n}(\mathbb{R})\,\middle|\,\begin{cases}
> f_{1}(A)=0\\
> .\\
> .\\
> .\\
> f_{n}(A)=0
> \end{cases}\right\}$
>
> Then a system of equations for $W$ is
>
> $\begin{cases}
> a_{k1}+...+a_{kn}=0\\
> .\\
> .\\
> .
> \end{cases}$

Is correct this? I have a serious doubt about this last part. Thanks for help, and for your time!

Comment: Thanks to @Gribouillis for his colaboration with this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part will be correct if $f_k$ is replaced by $\varphi_k$. However, note that the equations that you get are the equations that you started with, in the definition of $W$ (in spite of the fact that you only called them $\varphi_k$ later).

Comment: True Jose, sorry for the change of notation!. The part a) is correct for you?

Comment: @Bvss12 Yes, other than the fact that you did not prove that $\{\varphi_k\,|\,k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Jose Carlos, i think that is prove in the Edit$_2$

Comment: @Bvss12 Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

A simple equation for $W$ is
$$
W=\{M\in\operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R}):Mu=0\}
$$
where $u=[1\ 1\ \dotsm\ 1]^T$ is the $n\times1$ column with all $1$ entries.

In particular, $W=\ker T$, where $T$ is the linear map
$$
T\colon\operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}^n
\qquad
T(M)=Mu
$$
This map is easily seen to be surjective.

By the rank-nullity theorem,
$$
\dim W=\dim\ker T=\dim\operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})-\dim\mathbb{R}^n=n^2-n
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help egreg!!! Hey, can you see mi answer in this post ?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546630/prove-bigcap-i-1kkerf-i-subset-kerf-iff-f-in-spanf-1-f-k and the comment? i have a two little doubt here and you explain very good!! if you can!!!

Comment: @Bvss12 I added an answer