# Show that $\lambda<\alpha<\lambda h(x)+\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda _if_i(x) \quad\forall x\in E$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $E$ a vector space and $h,f_1,\cdots,f_n : E \to \mathbb R$ linear such that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^n \ker(f_i) \subset\ker h.$
Let $F : E\to \mathbb R^n : x\mapsto(h(x),f_1(x),\cdots,f_n(x))$.

- Show that $(1,0,\cdots,0)\not \in Im(F)$.
- Show the exitence of $(\lambda,\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)\in \mathbb R^{n+1}, \alpha\in \mathbb R$ :
  $\lambda<\alpha<\lambda h(x)+\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda _if_i(x) \quad\forall x\in E$

The first question is easy to prove bythe absurd but I got stuck in the second one. I know the factorisation of a map by other maps  as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546630/prove-bigcap-i-1k-kerf-i-subset-kerf-iff-f-in-rm-spanf-1-f-k) but this exercice is a proof of it .
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Handy Banach perhaps?

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? Is this a theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $F(E) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a closed subspace and $e_1 = (1,0,...,0) \notin F(E)$.

Hence the [Hahn Banach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#%22Geometric_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach%22_(the_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_separation_theorems)) gives the existence of some linear $\phi$ and some $\alpha$ such that $\phi(e_1) < \alpha < \phi(F(x))$ for all $x$.

Since $\phi$ is linear, it has the form
$\phi((h,f_1,...,f_n)) = \lambda h + \sum_k \lambda_k f_k$ from which we get the desired result.

Comment: I really appreciate your help ! Thanks a lot !